# jQuery and primefaces conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 3.5 with the jquery bundled inside of it. And i want to apply this small jquery code , it is a simple code , i added the behavior of the tab button to the enter button in the keyboard.

Here it is my code:

```
//<![CDATA[ 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":input").keyup(function (event) {

          if (event.keyCode == 13) {
               $(this).next().focus();
             }
     })
   }
);

//]]>
```

The code does not work , and there is no errors in the console.
I thought may be there was a conflict between my code and the jquery lib of primefaces
So what is the problem ???

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: No errors ,but the code doesnt work.

Comment: Debug and see if your code is being called...

Comment: @Java_User Everything seems just fine. Thats why i'm confused my friend.

Comment: @HatemAlimam i did debug it with firebug. No errors, No warnings.

Comment: @AnisBouchenafa Chek out my asnwer. Let us know if it solves your issue

Comment: @Java_User well i did not want to vote with -1. because honestly it wasn't an answer

Comment: You may post you xhtml page, maybe your jQuery selector won't match with the component you are applying the enter on...

Comment: @HatemAlimam i'm applying it on all the inputs ,and i know my code is not complete and general. In the first input when i pressed enter it loses focus , but when i try this code in a simple html view it works just fine. i wrote in jsfiddle.

Comment: @Java_User i did post a comment and i didnt vote with -1

Answer (score 3):

If there is a conflict,Try to resolve the conflict like

```
  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

and user $j on the place of $ in your JavaScript file.

Hope this resolve your conflict.

Comment: i tried it before i post the question, and nothing happened

Comment: Then its not the error of conflation.
Please find any other thin.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following code bellow the `<h:head`

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
<h:outputScript target="head">
    $ = jQuery;
</h:outputScript>
```